# Showing solutions to a system of ODEs approaches $0$ given constraints on initial data

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Assume the system $\dot x = A(t)x$ is uniformly asymptotically stable for $t_0\ge\beta$, some $\beta\in \mathbb{R}$, $t_0$ our initial starting time. Let $f: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous and such that for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\sigma>0$ such that $|x|<\sigma$ implies $|f(t,x)| <\sigma|x|$ for all $t$ (here $|\cdot |$ is the Euclidean norm). Additionally, suppose $b(t) \to 0$ as $t\to \infty$.

**Problem 1:** We want to show that there exists $T>\beta$ such that if $|x(T)|$ is "sufficiently small," then every solution to the system $\dot x = A(t)x +f(t,x) +b(t)$ approaches $0$ as $t\to \infty$.

**Problem 2:** After that, we want to generalize the result by replacing $b(t)$ with a function $g(t,x)$ that goes to $0$ as $t\to \infty$ uniformly for $x$ in compact sets.

For the first problem, if $b(t) \equiv 0$, then there's a theorem that tells us that $\dot x = A(t)x +f(t,x)$ is uniformly asymptotically stable as well, which means we are done. Since this need not be the case for general $b$, I tried to adapt the proof, but ran into some trouble:

Since $b(t) \to 0$ as $t\to \infty$, given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that $t>N$ implies $|b(t)|<\epsilon$. Additionally, by assumption on $f$, there exists $\sigma>0$ such that $|f(t,x)|<\epsilon|x|$ for $|x|<\sigma$ and for all $t$. Then, we fix a $T> \max\{N,\beta\}$. Utilizing Duhamel's formula, we can write any solution to the above system as
$$
x(t) = X(t)X^{-1}(T)x(T) + \int_T^t X(t)X^{-1}(s)[f(s,x(s))+b(s)]ds,
$$
where $X(t)$ is a fundamental matrix solution to the linear problem $\dot x= A(t)x$.
Now, since the linear system is uniformly asymptotically stable, there's a theorem that gives the existence of $K,\alpha >0$ such that (in particular) $|X(t)X^{-1}(s)|\le Ke^{-\alpha(t-s)}$ for all $T\le s \le t<\infty$. So for $|x| <\sigma$, we can utilize all the above to obtain the bound
$$
|x(t)| \le Ke^{-\alpha(t-T)}|x(T)| +\int_T^t \epsilon Ke^{-\alpha(t-s)}(|x(s)|+1) ds.
$$

From here, I'm a bit stuck. Given the limited tools available, my intuition says this is the way to go, but I don't know where to go next. The addition of the $b(t)$ prevents from using Gronwall's lemma to get exponential decay. In this case, we could do the generalized version (where one is adding a function of $t$ to the integral instead of a constant), but I tried that and couldn't get decay to $0$. Any help on this and Problem 2 would be greatly appreciated.